# Bash not equal string comparison

Tags: bash, shell-script

Why does this cause an infinite loop?

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ "$(ipcs | awk '{print $2}')" != "Semaphore" ]]; do
  #Gonna get rid of the echo after working
  echo "$(ipcs | awk '{print $2}')"
  #I want to keep this
  ipcrm shm "$(ipcs | awk '{print $2}')"
  #I want this run after breaking out of the loop until I reach the string
  #Message. 
  ipcrm -s "$(ipcs | awk '{print $2}')"
done      
echo
exit 0
```

I have verified I eventually get Semaphore so it should break out of the while loop.

```
$ echo $(ipcs | awk '{print $2}')
Shared shmid 262145 294914 2326531 Semaphore semid Message msqid


$ ipcs

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x00000000 262145     bob        600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 294914     bob        600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 2490371    bob        600        998400     2          dest         

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems     

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    

$ echo $(ipcs |  awk '{print $1}')
------ key 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 ------ key ------ key

$ echo $(ipcs |  awk '{print $2}')
Shared shmid 262145 294914 2490371 Semaphore semid Message msqid
```

Comment: Instead of `"Semaphore"`, you could use `*Semaphore*` without the quotes  (`""`).

Comment: which OS are you using ? From you sample, I suspect Semaphore is the first field, not the second. You sould also use `ipcs -s` to check only for Semaphore.

Comment: You're looking for a match of "...Semaphore..." to "Sempaphore". You need to make the string you're looking for a glob as well. With that check you're essentially saying `while [[ 1 ]]`.

Comment: @Archemar I want to remove the Semaphore. I added more comments.

Answer (score 4):

`$(ipcs | awk '{print $2}')` is never equal to `Semaphore`. It is always equal to:

```
Shared shmid 262145 294914 2326531 Semaphore semid Message msqid
```

You probably want something like:

```
for e in $(ipcs | awk '{print $2}'); do
    [[ "$e" = "Semaphore" ]] && break
    echo $e
done

echo
exit 0
```

You might also like this `awk` solution:

```
ipcs | awk '$2 == "Semaphore" {exit;} $2 != "" {print $2}'
```

A little explanation:

- If the second field is *Semaphore*, exit.
- Otherwise, if this field isn't empty, print it.

Here are a few alternative solutions (assuming I did understand your needs here) :

```
# List all shared memory segments keys
ipcs -m | awk 'NR > 3 && $1 != "" {print $1}'

# List all shared memory segments IDs
ipcs -m | awk 'NR > 3 && $2 != "" {print $2}'
```

For each of these examples, you can iterate over the result:

```
for e in $(above command); do
    echo $e
done
```

Comment: how are Semaphore and Semaphore not equal? I would think when they are equal it would exit.

Comment: Your `$(...)` result is **never** equal to semaphore. It is always equal to the full line (`Shared ...`). Since your `!=` is never met, the loop never ends. You don't want to test the whole result every time, you want to iterate over it: this is what the for-loop is designed to do. Here, I iterate over the result, and break the loop when I meet `Semaphore`, which is what you seemed to be trying to do with your `while` loop.

Comment: To put it simpler, ipcs output contains `Semaphore`, but it is not `Semaphore` only.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith so bash while loops don't have the ability to read one line at a time? I would think $2 would be equal to Shared, then shmid, then 262145, then 294914, then 2326531, then Semaphore, then semid, then Message msqid. Thats not exactly what I was trying to do. I edited my comment above. I want a command to be executed until I reach the string "Semaphore". Then I want another command to be executed until I reach the string "Message"

Comment: Bash while loops do have the ability to read one line at a time, but not the way you coded it. `$(some_command)` runs that command (to completion) and squashes its output to a single line. See slm's answer for how to do what you want.

Comment: @cokedude since this seems to have answered your question (given that you're using this code in your [new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/160359/22222)) you might want to consider [accepting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it which will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different way to approach your while loop:

```
$ while read line; do 
    echo "$line"; 
    if [[ "$line" != *Semaphore* ]]; then 
        echo "not semaphore"; 
    else 
        echo "is semaphore"; 
    fi;
  done < <(ipcs | awk '{print $2}')
```

Which produces this output:

```
...
not semaphore
814972976
not semaphore
815005745
not semaphore
817070167
not semaphore

not semaphore
Semaphore
is semaphore
semid
not semaphore
```

Notice when it gets to the string "Semaphore" it properly identifies it.