# Better way to run single for loop instead of two for loops

Tags: bash, shell-script

This works but the way I did this is kind of silly. Is there a better way to do this?

```
for e in $(ipcs | awk '{print $2}'); do
    [[ "$e" = "Semaphore" ]] && break
    echo $e
    ipcrm shm $e
done

    echo $e outside for loop
for e in $(ipcs | awk '{print $2}'); do
    [[ "$e" = "Message" ]] && break
    echo $e
    ipcrm -s $e
done

echo
exit 0
```

This is what ipcs looks like for me when I run it.

```
$ ipcs

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x00000000 262145     bob        600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 2523138    bob        600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 2555907    bob        600        393216     2          dest         
0x00000000 3375108    bob        600        998400     2          dest         
0x00000000 3440645    bob        666        40         1                       

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems     
0x000005b1 262146     bob        600        6         

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages
```

I need to run these two commands on a regular basis.

```
ipcrm -s $(ipcs | grep bob | awk '{printf "%s ",$2}')
ipcrm  shm $(ipcs | grep bob | awk '{printf "%s ",$2}')
```

So I was thinking I could do something like this.

```
if [ `$(ipcs | grep Shared | awk '{print $2}')` == "Shared"]
ipcrm  shm $(ipcs | grep bob | awk '{printf "%s ",$2}')
```

I want to do that first behavior until $2 equals Semaphore.

```
if [ `$(ipcs | grep Semaphore | awk '{print $2}')` == "Semaphore"]
ipcrm -s $(ipcs | grep bob | awk '{printf "%s ",$2}'
```

So to summarize I want the first if block to run after I see "Shared". Then I want the second if block after I see "Semaphore".

Comment: You can use a `case` statement instead of two `if` statements on separate loops. Anyway I don't see what you are trying to achieve clearly enough.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand corretly, you want to run the command `ipcrm shm <ids>` for all Shared Memory Segments of the user bob. Then the command `ipcrm -s <ids>` for all Semaphore Arrays of user bob.

To accomplish that use the following commands (you don't have to loop in a script):

**For the Shared Memory Segments part:**

```
ipcrm shm $(ipcs -m | awk '$3=="bob" {printf "%s ",$2}')
```

**For the Semaphore Array part:**

```
ipcrm -s $(ipcs -s | awk '$3=="bob" {printf "%s ",$2}')
```

**Explanation:**

From the `ipcs` manpage:

```
   -m     shared memory segments
   -s     semaphore arrays
```

The `awk` part prints the ids only when the 3rd field is bob.

Comment: how does it tell the difference between the Semaphore Arrays and Shared Memory Segments block? You haven't done anything to account for that. As I said above I need to use both those commands on a regular basis so I would like a script. I don't wanna have to dig through my bash history every time or type it out every time.

Comment: @cokedude the `-s` and `-m` flag. It tells ipcs to only show Semaphore Arrays (-s) or Shared Memory Segments (-m). And of course you can put those two commands in a script (would be a small script).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe...

```
ipcs | sed -n '
    s/[^ ]*  *//
    /^Messages/q
    /^Semaphores/cshift
    /  *bob .*/!d;s///
    / /!s/./ipcrm $1 &/p
'| sh -s -- shm \-s
```

That deletes lines that do not contain the string *bob* as the third space delimited field *or* that do not have in their second field *Messages/Semaphores.*

It inserts the string `ipcrm $1 <field 2>` for those lines that remain. It quits input when matching *Messages* and it replaces a *Semaphores* match w/ `shift`.

`sed`'s output is interpreted by a shell process with two positionals *shm/-s*. So when `sed` says `shift` that shell stops running the command `ipcrm shm <field2>` and starts running `-s` in shms place.

I guess if you wanted a pure shell solution this comes close:

```
set -f; IFS='
'; for l in $(ipcs); 
do IFS=\ ;set -- $l
case "$1:$2:${3#bob}" in
(-*:Sh*) a=shm;; 
(-*:Se*) a=-s;; 
(-*:Me*) break 2;;
(*:*:) ipcrm "$a" "$2";;
esac; done
```

Answer (score -2):

As slm suggested on [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160227/80216),
I suggest doing this with a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop:

```
looking_at=
ipcs | while read key id owner other
do
      # Keep track of which section we’re in.
      if [ "$id" = "Shared" ]               # $id is the second field; i.e., $2.
      then
            looking_at=shm
      elif [ "$id" = "Semaphore" ]
      then
            looking_at=sem
      elif [ "$id" = "Message" ]
      then
            break
      fi
      if [ "$owner" = "bob" ]
      then
            if [ "$looking_at" = "shm" ]
            then
                  ipcrm shm "$id"
            elif [ "$looking_at" = "sem" ]
            then
                  ipcrm -s "$id"
            fi
      fi
done
```

This reads the output of the `ipcs` command one line at a time,
breaking out the first three fields as `key`, `id`, and `owner`. 
As the comment says,
we use the `looking_at` variable to keep track of which section we’re in. 
Then, on every line that contains `bob` in the third field,
we use `looking_at` to determine which `ipcrm` option to use.